# Chernoff Bounds for Independent Bernoulli Sums

Tags: bernoulli-distribution, probability-inequalities, moment-generating-function

What is wrong with this proof? Can you notice that? or I am wrong? In my opinion, in the R.H.S. of the inequality (3.2), the index of 'e' is negative but it must be positive if we use the given proof because if we insert $t=\displaystyle\frac{4a}{n}$ in $ e^{-ta}e^{\frac{nt^2}{8}}$ we get $e^{-ta}e^{\frac{2a^2}{n}}$

[image: Chernoff Bounds]

Comment: What would you be wrong about?  You haven't stated anything.  What makes you suspect there's a problem with this proof and what kind of problem do you think it is?

Comment: Check your algebra. Plugging $t = 4a/n$ into $-ta + nt^2/8$ gives $$-(4a/n)a + n(4a/n)^2/8 = -4a^2/n + 2a^2/n = -2a^2/n.$$

Comment: @whuber, Oh, that means I am wrong. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[This is mentioned as Hoeffding's Inequality in Measure Concentration section of Shalev-Shwartz and Ben-David’s ML book. The inequality in post follows from ${ a _i = 0, b _i = 1 }$ case.]

**Thm** [Hoeffding]: Let ${ X _1, \ldots, X _N }$ with ${ X _i \in [a _i, b _i] }$ be independent random variables. Then sums ${ S _N = \sum _{i=1} ^{N} X _i }$ satisfy ${ \mathbb{P}(S _N - \mathbb{E}[S _N] \geq t ) }$ ${ \leq \exp\left(\frac{-2 t ^2}{\sum _{i=1} ^{N} (b _i - a _i ) ^2} \right) }.$
**Pf**: Write ${ Z _i = X _i - \mathbb{E}[X _i] ,}$ now by Markov ${ \mathbb{P}(S _N - \mathbb{E}[S _N] \geq t ) }$ ${ = \mathbb{P}(\sum _{i =1} ^{N} Z _i \geq t ) }$ ${ = \mathbb{P}(e ^{\lambda \sum _{i=1} ^{N} Z _i } \geq e ^{\lambda t}) }$ ${ \leq \frac{1}{e ^{\lambda t}} \mathbb{E}[e ^{\lambda \sum _{i=1} ^{N} Z _i}] }$ ${ = e ^{-\lambda t} (\Pi _{i=1} ^{N} \mathbb{E}[e ^{\lambda Z _i}])  }.$ Notice ${  Z _i = X _i - \mathbb{E}[X _i]  }$ are in ${ [-(b _i -a _i), (b _i-a _i)] }$ with mean ${ 0 }.$ By **below lemma**, ${ \mathbb{P}(S _N - \mathbb{E}[S _N] \geq t ) }$ ${  \leq e ^{-\lambda t} (\Pi _{i=1} ^{N} \mathbb{E}[e ^{\lambda Z _i}]) }$ ${ \leq e ^{-\lambda t} e ^{\frac{\lambda ^2 \sum _{i=1} ^{N} (2(b _i - a _i)) ^2}{8} }}.$ The RHS as a function of ${ \lambda > 0 }$ is minimized at ${ \lambda = \frac{t}{\sum _{i=1} ^{N} (b _i - a _i) ^2} }.$ This minimum value of RHS is ${ \exp\left(\frac{-2 t ^2}{\sum _{i=1} ^{N} (b _i - a _i ) ^2} \right)},$ as needed.

**Lemma**: Let ${ Z \in [a,b] }$ be a random variable with ${ \mathbb{E}[Z] = 0 }.$ Then ${ \mathbb{E}[e ^{\lambda Z}] \leq \exp(\frac{\lambda ^2 (b-a) ^2}{8}) }$ for ${ \lambda > 0 }.$
**Pf**: The function ${ e ^{\lambda x} }$ is below line ${ e ^{\lambda a} + (\frac{e ^{\lambda b} - e ^{\lambda a}}{b-a}) (x-a) }$ on ${ [a,b] }.$ Taking expectation, ${\mathbb{E}[e ^{\lambda X}] \leq \frac{b e ^{\lambda a } - a e ^{ \lambda b }}{b-a} }.$ RHS is ${ e ^{\lambda a} (\frac{b}{b-a} - \frac{a}{b-a} e ^{\lambda (b-a)} ) }$ ${= e ^{\lambda a} (1 + \frac{a}{b-a} {\color{red}{- \frac{a}{b-a}}} e ^{{\color{blue}{\lambda (b-a)}}} )  }$ ${ = e ^{L(h)} }$ where ${ L(h) = -hp + \log(1-p+{\color{red}{p}} e^{\color{blue}{h}}) }$ with ${ {\color{red}{p = - \frac{a}{b-a}}} }$ and ${ {\color{blue}{h = \lambda (b-a)}} }.$ It suffices to show ${ L(h) \leq \frac{h ^2}{8} }.$ This follows from verifying ${ L(0) = L'(0) = 0 }$ and ${ L ^{''} (h) \leq \frac{1}{4} }$ for all ${ h > 0 }.$